# spring singleton scope

Tags: java, spring

Spring reference manual says:

The scope of the Spring singleton is best described as "per container and per bean".

consider this code snippet:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml")
MyBean myobj=(MyBean)context.getBean("myBean"); //myBean is of singleton scope.
MyBean myobj1=(MyBean)context.getBean("myBean");
```

`per container` means that if we do `context.getBean("myBean");` twice it will return same bean i.e. `myobj==myobj1` is `true`.

But what does `per bean` in `per container and per bean` from above  statement means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked another question in reference to this one:[spring singleton scope— per container per bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918066/spring-singleton-scope-per-container-per-bean)

From that I concluded following for `per bean` part of phrase `per container per bean`:

Consider:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml")
MyBean myobj=(MyBean)context.getBean("myBean"); 
MyBean myobj1=(MyBean)context.getBean("myBean"); 
MyBean myobj2=(MyBean)context.getBean("mySecondBean");
```

Beans.xml:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBean"/>
<bean id="mySecondBean" class="MyBean"/>
```

Now Singleton in Spring is `per container per bean`.

`per container` means if we get *same bean id* by `getBean()` within *same container* then they represent  same instances.Therefore  `myobj==myobj1` is true.

And if we get bean with same id in two *different containers* then they will represent two different instances.This is represented in answer above given by **Nirmal- thInk beYond**.

But for singleton, within `per container` it should also be `per bean`(per bean tag).

i.e if we define two beans in configuration file *of same class* then they represent *different instances* even within *same container*.

Thats why `myobj==myobj2` is false.

Answer (score 4):

in simple way

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml")
MyBean myobj=(MyBean)context.getBean("myBean"); //myBean is of singleton scope.

ApplicationContext context1= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml")
MyBean myobj1=(MyBean)context1.getBean("myBean");

myobj==myobj1 would not be same
```

Comment: What do you mean by "myobj==myobj1 would not be same"? Both are the same object so they are `==`.

Comment: @ Tichodroma: actually he means myobj==myobj1 is false.

Comment: @Tichodroma: yes, myobj==myobj1 is false means myobj and myobj1 not same bean

Comment: Also see another question of the same author http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918066/spring-singleton-scope-per-container-per-bean

Answer (score 3):

Spring bean container will create single bean for singleton scoped beans, if you have another container of spring the different bean would get created

so per container there would be single instance of bean (for singleton scoped beans)

Comment: u have described `per container` part of phrase `per container and per bean` i.e singleton bean remains `singleton per container`. BUT what does the `per bean`  indicates in phrase `per container and per bean`? OR  i am just confusing with the language of phrase.

Comment: if you configure 2 beans of the same class, then there would be 2 instances of that class in container, since there are two beans defined